# Adding a png to clipboard

Tags: c#, png, clipboard, dataformat

I have a simple question. What do I use as a DataFormat when saving a png to the clipboard.

An example that works for Bitmaps is:

```
DataObject data = new DataObject();
data.SetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, customObject.ToImage(ImageFormat.Bmp));
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data);
```

My problem:

```
DataObject data = new DataObject();
data.SetData(DataFormats.**???**, customObject.ToImage(ImageFormat.Png));
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data);
```

Comment: `DataFormats.*` are just strings, you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register any serializable type with the clipboard provider:

```
        Image image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Documents\Projects\....\myimage.png");
        DataFormat format = DataFormats.GetDataFormat(typeof (Image).FullName);

        IDataObject dataObj = new DataObject();
        dataObj.SetData(format.Name, image);

        Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);

        IDataObject clipboardObj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        Image clipboardImage = (Image)clipboardObj.GetData(format.Name);
```

Comment: The string "PNG" is accepted as clipboard image format in many applications, but it requires a `MemoryStream` containing the PNG image's bytes.